# MS Edge (Chromium) - Cannot use Selenium WebDriver

Tags: python, macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I am trying to use the Microsoft Edge (Chromium) WebDriver for Selenium on macOS.

I downloaded the official binary from the Microsoft website, and included it in my project folder. I am attempting to use it in my Python application as such:

```py
import os, sys
from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge, EdgeOptions

work_root = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
edgedriver = os.path.join(work_root, 'driver/msedgedriver')

options = EdgeOptions()
options.use_chromium = True
options.add_argument("headless")
options.add_argument("disable-gpu")

sys.path.append(edgedriver)

driver = Edge(edgedriver, options = options)

driver.get("https://www.microsoft.com")
print(driver.page_source)
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```sh
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /Users/den/Documents/GitHub/my_project/driver/msedgedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -6
```

The web driver version *should* match the version of the installed Edge browser.

What is this status code and what might I be missing in my code?

Comment: From the error message, it can be possible that you had downloaded the incorrect version of the web driver. I suggest trying to check the version of the Edge browser and then try to download the compatible version of the web driver from [this link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/). [See here](https://imgur.com/a/XxxTgYV). After that again try to run the code, it may help you to fix this issue.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT unfortunately that doesn't seem to be the case - I've downloaded the version that matches the installed Edge version, and I still get the same error.

Comment: If you double click the Edge web driver, are you able to run it successfully? Please inform us which version of the Edge browser you are using? Which version of the web driver did you download? Which version of the Mac OS you are using for making this test?